# Visual C++ Watch for key sequence

Tags: .net, c++-cli, keyboard-shortcuts, capture

If I have some form application in C++, how would I set something up so that it watches for a specific key sequence to perform some action? Like, for instance, watching for the user to tap arrow keys in a specific order, and when it happens open up another form?

(aparrantly this is .net? i'm new to doing forms, so i'm a little lost here.)

Comment: YOu do not specify what API you are using.  Is this straight Win32, or MFC, or what???

Comment: With winapi, keep an index that moves via a hook.

Comment: Not sure, whatever Visual C++'s default for "Windows Forms Application" is. I'd assume that's win32. This is my first foray past console applications, so I'm not entirely certain.

Comment: Probably .NET, actually, if it's Windows Forms. That's not really C++, it's C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you're okay requiring that the main `Form` have focus, a simple version involves setting the `KeyPreview` property to `true` and adding a handler for `PreviewKeyDown`:

```
#using <System::Windows::Forms.dll>

// for brevity of example
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

public ref class Form1 : Form
{
private:
    // desired key sequence
    static array<Keys>^ contra = { Keys::Up, Keys::Up, Keys::Down, Keys::Down,
                                   Keys::Left, Keys::Right, Keys::Left, Keys::Right,
                                   Keys::B, Keys::A, Keys::LaunchApplication1};

    // how far into the sequence the user currently is
    int keySeqPos;

    // some other data
    int lives;

    void Form1_PreviewKeyDown(Object^ sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs^ e)
    {
        if{keySeqPos < 0 || keySeqPos >= contra->Length)
        {
            // reset position if it's invalid
            keySeqPos = 0;
        }

        // use the following test if you don't care about modifiers (CTRL, ALT, SHIFT)
        // otherwise you can test direct equality: e->KeyCode == contra[keySeqPos]
        // caps lock, num lock, and scroll lock are harder to deal with
        if(e->KeyCode & Keys.KeyCode == contra[keySeqPos])
        {
            keySeqPos++
        }
        else
        {
            keySeqPos = 0;
            // alternatively, you could keep a history and check to see if a
            // suffix of it matches a prefix of your code, setting keySeqPos to
            // the length of the match
        }

        if(keySeqPos == contra->Length)
        {
            // key sequence complete, do whatever it is you want to do
            lives += 3;
        }
    }

    void InitializeComponent()
    {
        // other initialization code

        this->KeyPreview = true;
        this->PreviewKeyDown += gcnew PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(this, &Form1::Form1_PreviewKeyDown);
    }

public:

    Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        keySeqPos = 0;
        lives = 3;
    }
}
```